Pyspark looping though the values in a distributed way
I have the below requirement to be developed using Azure databricks (pyspark).

Call the Azure SQL database to read a column from the table.
For each column value, read above, call a REST API, which returns a JSON response.
Convert JSON to parquet and store in ADLS2 location.

For now, the approach I have tried
  df = spark.read.format("jdbc")...
  idList = df.select("id").rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
 
  finallist = []

  for id in idList :
     resp = requests.get(...)
     finallist.append(resp.text)

  df1 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(finallist)   
  df2 = spark.read.json(df1)
  df2.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("abfs://....adls2 path...")

Above approach is tested with few sample data and seem to be working fine. However, I have a doubt in the above approach when it comes to scalability.
After collecting the ids from table, I am looping through them with for loop to pass that id to the rest API call that I will be making and then appending the API response to a list. This will run on driver so won't be running in a distributed way.I am adding the API response to the list so that I can parallelize the API response into distributed collection that can run on multiple workers later when I convert the JSON to Parquet.
How can I run all of my code in a distributed way? What's the better and efficient approach to handle my use-case? May be I can use foreach to call the APIs but then how do I convert JSON response to Parquet in a distributed way.
Please note that even though collect() will only bring a column value to the driver but it's not a bottleneck for me as driver has enough memory.

Is the structure of JSON from REST API same in all call? and is the structure known prior to the call?

you can use UDF to output a string that can be saved in the df's column. this column can then be transformed

@RakeshGovindula yes the structure is same and known

Is the response from the JSON is a JSON object or a JSON array?

response is JSON object

@Anand, Is the below answer resolved your queries?

@RakeshGovindula haven't tried it yet due to vacations. Will try and update you.

Is it working ?

I do agree with @samkart's comment. To achieve your requirement, you can use a UDF to store each API response as JSON string in the same dataframe column, then use from_json() to extract the required values from the JSON string column.
Here is a sample demo where I have used a dataframe df with column sql_id.
+------+
|sql_id|
+------+
|     1|
|     2|
|     3|
|     4|
|     5|
+------+

For sample, I have used https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{<sql_id>} API from JSON placeholder by passing the sql_id to the UDF which will return the JSON response as a string. You need to use your API in this.
import requests
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
from pyspark.sql.functions import from_json,col

# Create UDF to get the JSON from API
def json_api(sql_id):
    try:
        response = requests.get(f"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{sql_id}")
        if response.status_code == 200:
            return response.text
        else:
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        return None

# Set the return type as string
upi_udf = udf(json_api, StringType())

# creates new column named response with api json as json string
df_api_data = df.withColumn("response", upi_udf(df["sql_id"]))

df_api_data.display()

# Extract the JSON schema from the JSON string column
json_schema = spark.read.json(df_api_data.rdd.map(lambda row: row.response)).schema

# Use from_json() and give the schema
res_df = df_api_data.withColumn('new_json', from_json(col('response'), json_schema)).select('sql_id','new_json.*')

res_df.display()

After saving the JSON string as a new column, use rdd and lambda function to extract the JSON schema or you can build the JSON schema as you already knew the JSON structure.
Now, create the JSON object column new_json using from_json() and pass this json_schema to it. Then, use select on this column to get the required columns from the dataframe.
Sample Result:



sql_id
completed
id
title
userId




1
false
1
delectus aut autem
1


2
false
2
quis ut nam facilis et officia qui
1


3
false
3
fugiat veniam minus
1


4
true
4
et porro tempora
1


5
false
5
laboriosam mollitia et enim quasi adipisci quia provident illum
1



